# Up to what model size can a JXTable work properly?

Tags: java, swing, jxtable

I am building a Swing UI for analysis data dealing with potentially hundreds of thousands of rows (only a handful of columns) and I would like to use a JXTable for visualization with filtering and sorting. Is there a rule of thumb up to what size this is feasible on a fast computer provided I don't make mistakes when building model, renderer, filter, sorter classes?

Comment: Try it. Just create a loop that loads a bunch of rows and see what happens. The reason a JTable uses renderers is so that the amount of data really doesn't matter because you only display a screen full of data at a time. Of course filtering/sorting will probably be slower because you need to process more data and store more data.

Comment: In addition to camickr's comment: do really want to show hundreds of thousands of rows to the user? Maybe pagination would be useful.

Comment: So far it looks good enough performance-wise (haven't tried filtering yet). Regarding pagination, I have thought about that but I don't know of an out-of-the box solution and was reluctant to hacking it together.